# How to centrally monitor messages sent to application or winform

Tags: c#, winforms, message-queue, message

How can I catch  messages for all windows from one central place in my application (winforms). I need one central place in my application (e.g. programm.cs or Mainform) that can react to every Creation or alternate every showing (WM_FORMSHOW 0x18) of a Form. Forms are copntributed from other developers, AddIns, but they are activated in the default appdomain. Allthough activation in another appdomain would be an interesting case too.

the Enviroment is .Net 3.5 or 4 and c#.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can trap windows messages by creating an [`IMessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx), and adding it to the application via [`Application.AddMessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx).

Inside your `IMessageFilter` implementation class, you implement `PreFilterMessage`, where you can look for whatever you want - it is passed a [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.aspx) that contains the same data a C-style windows message loop would get.  Note that you can also add a `IMessageFilter` to a specific form if you wish, as as the entire Application message loop.

Comment: Using Application.AddMessageFilter not all messages seem to be availabble, especially not "WM_SHOWWINDOW  0x0018"

Comment: I have access to WM_SHOWWINDOW  0x0018 when overriding WndProc(ref Message m). But this is a method of the form and gives me access to the message only if it is handled by this form. Unfortunately the forms are part of addins, and I do not have any access to their code, to override this method